# ASP.NET Post API Call doesnt find the controller route. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, blazor

I want to make an Post api call. the get method works without any problems, but the post call doesnt find the route. idk why...

Here's the Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.Supervisor)]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class SupportUserManagementController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SupportUserService _supportUsersService;

    public SupportUserManagementController(SupportUserService supportUserService)
    {
        this._supportUsersService = supportUserService;
    }

    // GET: api/GetSupportUsersListAsync
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Test2")]
    [Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.User)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ScopeSupportUsers>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [SwaggerOperation("GetSupportUsers")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ScopeSupportUsers>> GetSupportUsers(int id)
    {
        var result = await _supportUsersService.GetSupportUsersListAsync(id);
        return result;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Test3")]
    [Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.User)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Guid?), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [SwaggerOperation("CreateSupportUsers")]
    public async Task<Guid?> CreateSupportUsers(int id, ScopeSupportUsers user)
    {
        var existingUser = await GetSupportUsers(id);
        var matches = existingUser.Where(u => u.Name == user.Name);

        if (matches.Count() != 0)
        {
            return Guid.Empty;
        }

        var resultGuid = await _supportUsersService.CreateSupportUserAsync(id, user);
        if (resultGuid != null)
        {
            var resultCertificate = await SetCertificate_1Async(id, user, (Guid)resultGuid);
            if (resultCertificate == true)
                return resultGuid;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Why does this work:

```
using var client = await httpClientHelper.GetHttpClientWithAccessToken();
    string uri = $"{_serviceClientOptions.Value.BetriebstoolServiceAddress}/api/SupportUserManagement/Test2?id={selectedScope}";
    supportUserResult = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<ScopeSupportUsers>>(uri);
```

And this doesnt work?

```
using var client = await httpClientHelper.GetHttpClientWithAccessToken();
            string uri = $"{_serviceClientOptions.Value.BetriebstoolServiceAddress}/api/SupportUserManagement/Test3?id={selectedScopeToCopyTo}";
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<ScopeSupportUsers>(uri , user);
```

If i am debugging the GET works fine but at the POST Method it doesnt find the "way" to the controller"

This Breakpoint never reached :(
[image]

Comment: Use `[FromBody]` or its part of the action signature... `CreateSupportUsers(int id, [FromBody] ScopeSupportUsers user)`. Also your return value is a `Guid?` but your call expects a `ScopeSupportUsers`.

Comment: but the Scopesupportuser isn't the return value i think. if i write `client.PostAsJsonAsync<Guid?>(uri , user);` then i get a cannot convert from scopesupportuser to guid?. So this is the value i give with the call. isn't it?

Comment: My bad when I use `PostAsJsonAsync<>` I am normally expecting back what I posted as sometimes the DB updates the properties for example Id's are sometimes assigned by the database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-7.0 . You can remove the <> part as the post type can be derived and process the `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: oke thank you, did that but i posted e screenshot and if you look at the breakpoint which never reached. I get a 400 Bad Request as answer. Why does the route to the controller not work? thank's :)

Comment: It's because the method is expecting and id from the query, which is not defined in the route. use [HttpPost("{id}")]

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, but id didn't work. The id is defined in the route if you watch the call uri: `/api/SupportUserManagement/Test3?id={selectedScopeToCopyTo}` And why do i did not need this at the GET api call?

Comment: You probably need to provide parameter source attributes `public async Task<Guid?> CreateSupportUsers([FromQuery]int id, [FromBody]ScopeSupportUsers user)`

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks, but unfortunately that isn's the solution :(